# Bubble shooter search alghoritm

Tags: game-mechanics, search

So I have a Matrix of NxM. At a given position (for ex. [2][5]) I have a value which represents a color. If there is nothing at that point the value is -1. What I need to do is after I add a new point, to check all his neighbours with the same color value and if there are more than 2, set them all to -1.

If what I said doesn't make sense what I'm trying to do is an alghoritm which I use to destroy all the same color bubbles from my screen, where the bubbles are memorized in a matrix where -1 means no bubble and {0,1,2,...} represent that there is a bubble with a specific color.

This is what I tried and failed:

```
public class Testing {

    static private int[][] gameMatrix=
        {{3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0},
        {1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0},
        {2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        };

    static int Rows=6;
    static int Cols=10;
    static int count;
    static boolean[][] visited=new boolean[15][15];
    static int NOCOLOR = -1;
    static int color = 1;

    public static void dfs(int r, int c, int color, boolean set)
    {
        for(int dr = -1; dr <= 1; dr++) 
            for(int dc = -1; dc <= 1; dc++)
                if(!(dr == 0 && dc == 0) && ok(r+dr, c+dc))
                {
                    int nr = r+dr;
                    int nc = c+dc;

                    // if it is the same color and we haven't visited this location before
                    if(gameMatrix[nr][nc] == color && !visited[nr][nc]) 
                    {
                        visited[nr][nc] = true;
                        count++;

                        dfs(nr, nc, color, set);

                        if(set)
                        {
                            gameMatrix[nr][nc] = NOCOLOR;
                        }
                    }
                }
    }

    static boolean ok(int r, int c)
    {
        return r >= 0 && r < Rows && c >= 0 && c < Cols;
    }

    static void showMatrix(){
        for(int i = 0; i < gameMatrix.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("[");
            for(int j = 0; j < gameMatrix[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(" " + gameMatrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println(" ]");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

    static void putValue(int value,int row,int col){
        gameMatrix[row][col]=value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Initial Matrix:"); 
        putValue(1, 4, 1);
        putValue(1, 5, 1);
        showMatrix();

        for(int n = 0; n < 15; n++)
            for(int m = 0; m < 15; m++)
                visited[n][m] = false;

        //reset count
        count = 0;
        //dfs(bubbles.get(i).getRow(), bubbles.get(i).getCol(), color, false); 

        // get the contiguous count
        dfs(5,1,color,false);
        //if there are more than 2 set the color to NOCOLOR
        for(int n = 0; n < 15; n++)
            for(int m = 0; m < 15; m++)
                visited[n][m] = false;
        if(count > 2)
        {
            //dfs(bubbles.get(i).getRow(), bubbles.get(i).getCol(), color, true);
            dfs(5,1,color,true);
        }

        System.out.println("Matrix after dfs:");
        showMatrix();
    }

}
```

Comment: You should write more - what have failed? Give us some output :)

Comment: Well the matrix remains the same after dfs although it should set the some of the elements to -1.

Comment: ok I fixed it.:D

Comment: i am trying to implement same in objective C , but facing same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need here is a depth first search.

```
  int R, C;
  int[][] matrix;
  int count;
  boolean[][] visited;
  int NOCOLOR = -1;
  public int main()
  {
    int startR = 0;
    int startC = 0;
    int color = 1 // red
    int R = 10;
    int C = 20;


    matrix = new int[R][C];
    visited = new boolean[R][C];

    matrix = LoadLevel(); // get a starting matrix with colors

    //reset visited matrix to false.
    for(int i = 0; i < R; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < C; j++)
            visited[i][j] = false;

    //reset count
    count = 0;
    dfs(startR, startC, color, false); // get the contiguous count

    //if there are more than 2 set the color to NOCOLOR
    if(count > 2)
    {
        dfs(startR, startC, color, true);
    }
  }

  public void dfs(int r, int c, int color, boolean set)
  {
    for(int dr = -1; dr <= 1; dr++)
        for(int dc = -1; dc <= 1; dc++)
            if((dr == 0 ^ dc == 0) && ok(r+dr, c+dc)) // 4 neighbors
            {
                int nr = r+dr;
                int nc = c+dc;

                // if it is the same color and we haven't visited this location before
                if(matrix[nr][nc] == color && !visited[nr][nc]) 
                {
                    visited[nr][nc] = true;
                    count++;

                    dfs(nr, nc, color, set);

                    if(set)
                    {
                        matrix[nr][nc] = NOCOLOR;
                    }
                }
            }
  }

    boolean ok(int r, int c)
    {
      return r >= 0 && r < R && c >= 0 && c < C;
    }
```

Comment: Oh. Nice! With code and everything. After a first look this seems legit so good answer. I'll provide some feedback after trying it.

Comment: Please see my edit. :D

Comment: You call dfs(nr, nc, color) need 1 more param :D

Comment: fixed recursive call parameter

Comment: If you want to change it from 4 neighbors to 8 neighbors replace the if statement with this:  if(!(dr == 0 && dc == 0) && ok(r+dr, c+dc)) // 8 neighbors

Comment: Thanks I didn't get it working yet as I am missing something but hopefully I'll do it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I keep finding better ways to do this. But instead of running the second dfs and using the set boolean, you can just do a double for loop through the visited array using the i, j index you set the matrix to NOCOLOR if the visited spot is true.

Comment: You missed a = sign and to reset the boolean values after calling once dfs. Although you made it really nice :D

Comment: i wrote it in notepad++ and didn't compile it, so sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: +1. Be aware that recursive functions can hit performance due to the ongoing assignment of stack frames at each recursion level. You can easily modify the basic algorithm to use a stack data structure to take the place of the system stack, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration). But I wouldn't change it unless you've profiled and seen that this is impacting performance more than a little.

Comment: Can you guys  add the code to start DFS from top, so we can get the unvisited node those should fall.here is my post you want to know the details.  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69392/verify-which-bubble-is-connected-to-top-using-dfs

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easy to implement [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to search same colors. You can just go to all of it's neighbours and then to their neighbours (if they are of the same color) etc.

So you will create graph, where every point is connected to its four- (or eight-) neighborhood.