# Verify which bubble is connected to top using DFS

Tags: algorithm, game-mechanics, cocos2d-iphone, path-finding, search

I am working on a bubble shooter game in this game i have implemented searching using `DFS` as suggested in this [link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27927/bubble-shooter-falling-algorithm?rq=1), and this is working fine.

**Update**

Here is my code for DFS

```
-(void)callDfs:(int)startR:(int)startC:(int)color{

notVisitedBubblesArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


//reset visited matrix to false.
for(int i = 0; i < R; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < C; j++)
        visited[i][j] = FALSE;

//reset count
count = 0;
isFound = NO;
bubbleBlastCount = 0;
[self dfs:startR :startC :color :false];

[self bubbleFalling];


}
-(void)dfs:(int)ro:(int)co:(int)colori:(BOOL)set{
    coundown++;
    for(int dr = -1; dr <= 1; dr++)
        for(int dc = -1; dc <= 1; dc++)
            if([self ok:ro+dr :co+dc]) // 4 neighbors
            {
                int nr = ro+dr;
                int nc = co+dc;

                if ((([[[bubbles_Arr objectAtIndex:nr] objectAtIndex:nc]   integerValue]==colori) && !visited[nr][nc])) {
visited[nr][nc] = true;
count++;
[self dfs:nr :nc :colori :set];
if(count>2)
{
// pass row and colom will start dfs
//  if (nr >= touchClum && nc >= touchROW) {
isFound = YES;
bubbleBlastCount++;
[[bubbles_Arr objectAtIndex:nr] replaceObjectAtIndex:nc withObject:NOCOLOR];
[bubbles[nc+1][nr+1] setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"blank.png"]];
}
}
}
}
```

Now i am trying to implement bubble falling using DFS, i studied this [link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27927/bubble-shooter-falling-algorithm?rq=1). i got all unvisited nodes after DFS but i am not able to verify with node is connected to top.

Here is my code for bubble falling

```
-(void)bubbleFalling{

for(int i = 0; i < R; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < C; j++){    
if (!visited[i][j]) {
    //NSLog(@"Array :  %d %d", i,j);

    NSLog(@"Value : %d",[[[bubbles_Arr objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j] integerValue]);

    BOOL canReach = [self canreachTop:i :j];
    if(canReach){
        NSLog(@"Yes");


    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"NO");
        [[bubbles_Arr objectAtIndex:i] replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:NOCOLOR];
        [bubbles[j+1][i+1] setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"blank.png"]];
    }

}


    }
}
}

-(BOOL)canreachTop:(int)ro:(int)co{
   int topNode = [[[bubbles_Arr objectAtIndex:R-1]objectAtIndex:C-1] integerValue];

BOOL success = FALSE;
for(int dr = -1; dr <= 1; dr++)
    for(int dc = -1; dc <= 1; dc++)

        if([self ok:ro+dr :co+dc]) // 4 neighbors
        {
            int nr = ro+dr;
            int nc = co+dc;

            if ((([[[bubbles_Arr objectAtIndex:nr] objectAtIndex:nc] integerValue]== topNode) && !visited[nr][nc])) {
            success = TRUE;
            }
        }

return success;
}


-(BOOL)ok:(int)r:(int)c{
    return r >= 0 && r < R && c >= 0 && c < C;
}
```

Below is the screenshot of my iPhone simulator in that green bubble should fall because it is not connected with any bubble, i think we have to check whether it is connected with the top bubble or not or i have to follow some other approach?

[image: screenshot]

This is my first game and i am not getting what is wrong with my bubble falling code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I don't want to implement flood-fill", I hope there is a reason other than I don't want to? Another thing, If you already implemented search using DFS, I don't see how falling bubbles are different can you elaborate ?

Comment: As far as i understand searching can be implemented using `flood-fill` and `DFS`, so i have implemented `DFS`.
Now i have already implemented DFS so why should i implement another algorithm.

Comment: Yes, my primary question is why a falling bubble is different. your question is not clear in its current form.

Comment: Bubble falling is not different, i am not able to find a way to implement this using DFS.

Comment: Just start searching from the falling bubble not the other way around, this way you check the newest falling bubble is connected to which bubble. And not which bubble is connected to the falling bubble.

Comment: If you need to know which bubbles are at the top, you need to define that to the computer. For instance, you could define that the top row of bubbles is linked to a special node named top.

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite yes i have define that but i am not able to find my bubble is not connected to top bubble.

Comment: You check if there is an edge between a bubble and the top. Maybe you could show the relevant code.

Comment: Have you studied this [link](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24419/bubble-shooter-search-alghoritm/24424#24424) ?

Comment: Without further details on how you're implementing things, it's unclear what kind of answer you're expecting here. Depending how you're using DFS, it should be suitable for this situation. You may want to confirm your code is working properly by using the debugger.

Comment: @Byte56 - Hello i have updated my question, is it clear now?

Comment: @LuisEstrada - Yes i have studied that i have implemented that as well, please check my updated question.

Comment: small tip for writing questions: put the actual question at the top, don't bury it in the middle of a long post.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using DFS starting from the top, all unvisited nodes should drop.
The top should be an invisible node connected to all top bubbles (in the top row).
One thing worth noting, is that unlike the current DFS which is checking for color equality, the functionality you should use for deciding which bubbles to drop because they are hanging in the air should ignore color and simply be content with bubbles being accessible from the top.

1. Run DFS from the newly added bubble with same color condition to see which bubbles to drop.
2. Run DFS from the top with no color condition and drop all bubbles that are hanging in the air.

I will try to clear it up. You are checking if a bubble can reach the top.. Don't. Run your DFS starting from the top and simply remove (drop) unvisited nodes.

Comment: No if bubble color doesn't match bubble can't fall.

Comment: If the color doesn't match but the bubble is hanging in the air it should fall.

Comment: Yes for the bubble falling there is no need of color matching, but if we only drop unvisited node some other bubbles fall as well.
In `canReachTop` method i have put a condition `if ((([[[bubbles_Arr objectAtIndex:nr] objectAtIndex:nc] integerValue]== topNode) && !visited[nr][nc])) {` if i remove color condition many other bubbles falls.

Comment: There are two steps here. 1. Check which bubbles are same color and could be visited (with DFS) from the bubble you just shot. 2. Check which bubbles are still accessible from the top, drop the rest. It's two different kinds of DFS, one checks for color, the other does not.

Comment: in second step you suggested that we need to check which bubble is accessible from top, if you see the question that is all we need to do **verify which bubble is connected to top**.

Comment: Yes by running DFS from the top without the color condition, all unvisited nodes are not connected to the top.

Comment: OK I'll try that, and I'll let u know.

Comment: I think you are right we have to run DFS from the top with color check, but when i tried to run DFS from top my app was crashed.
i am passing last row and last column in my DFS method below is my loop that is creating problem. 
`for(int dr = -1; dr <= 1; dr--)
        for(int dc = -1; dc <= 1; dc--)`

Comment: @Hemant Your application was crashing because it seems that you are using a recursive DFS, use an iterative DFS with a stack.

Comment: @concept3d Can you give me some more details about iterative DFS in my scenario, because i am very new to DFS and this is my very first game.